# shows extra comma before the list.How to avoid that?

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter,when I try to add the values of a list to another list, the newly created list shows a comma at the first position. The second list is initially empty.

The list is created inside the getx controller class

```
 RxList dayNames = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'].obs;
  RxList repeatedDays = [].obs;
```

The function is:-

```
Obx(()=>
                     Column(
                      children: [
                        ... List.generate(
                        addNewDishController.dayNames.length, (index){
                          return InkWell(
                            onTap: (){
                              print(addNewDishController.dayNames[index]);

                                if(addNewDishController.repeatedDays.contains(addNewDishController.dayNames[index])){
                                  addNewDishController.repeatedDays.remove(addNewDishController.dayNames[index]);
                                }else{
                                  addNewDishController.repeatedDays.add(addNewDishController.dayNames[index]);
                                  print(addNewDishController.repeatedDays);
                                }
                            },
```

The new list is printed in the console like this:-

```
[log] List:- [, Thursday, Wednesday]
```

I am expecting list like this

```
[log] List:- [Thursday, Wednesday]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably doing this because you initialized your repeated days list as [], where it just treats the emptiness as a literal and adds a comma next to it in your output. To get rid of this you can declare your repeateddays list as

`RxList repeatedDays = List<String>.empty().obs;`

Hope it helps